Is the application of medicalSpeciality and additionalProperty in schema of type Physician correct?
In the below schema of type Phycisian is the use of medicalSpeciality and additionalProperty correct?
In the Physician schema type there is no Qualification property.
If not what should I do to include Qualification and Medical specialties of the physicians?
Could someone guide me through this?
Should I use schema type person instead?
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Physician",
   "image" : "https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/campaign/Dr-suhas-patil.jpg",
    "telephone": "+91 7411951943",
    "priceRange":"INR 500 - INR 1000",
    "address":[  
        { 
            "@type": "PostalAddress", 
            "streetAddress": "Healing hands clinic Baner Rd, Laxman Nagar, Baner, Pune, Maharashtra 411045, India, Maharashtra 411001", 
            "addressLocality": "Pune", 
            "addressRegion": "Maharashtra", 
            "postalCode": "411001", 
            "addressCountry": "India" 
        }, 
        { 
            "@type": "PostalAddress", 
            "streetAddress": "Second floor, Premier Plaza,Near Big Bazar & Big Cinema,Above Mac Donald, Chinchwad, Pune - 411019", 
            "addressLocality": "Pune", 
            "addressRegion": "Maharashtra", 
            "postalCode": "411019", 
            "addressCountry": "India" 
        },
        { 
            "@type": "PostalAddress", 
            "streetAddress": "Gokul Complex,Near HDFC Bank,Wage VastiNashik Road,Chakan, Pune - 410501", 
            "addressLocality": "Pune", 
            "addressRegion": "Maharashtra", 
            "postalCode": "410501", 
            "addressCountry": "India" 
        }  
    ],
 "url" : "https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in",
     "founders":
{
"@type": "Person",
"name": "Dr Ashwin Porwal"
},
"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": "4.9",
"reviewCount": "1000"
},
"areaServed": {
"@type": "State",
"name": "Maharashtra"
},
 "sameAs" : [ "https://www.facebook.com/HealingHandsClinic",
    "https://twitter.com/hhc_pune",
    "https://plus.google.com/u/0/+HealinghandsclinicCoIn",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/drashwinporwal", 
    "https://www.youtube.com/user/hhcpune", 
    "https://www.pinterest.com/healinghandsc/", 
    "https://www.instagram.com/healinghandsclinic/" 
],
  "name":"Dr Suhas Patil",
         "knowsLanguage":[
        {
       "@type":"Language",
       "name":"English"
       },
        {
       "@type":"Language",
       "name":"Hindi"
       },
       {
       "@type":"Language",
       "name":"Marathi"
       }
       ], 
"medicalSpecialty":[
   {  "@type":"MedicalSpecialty",
        "name":"Hernia"
   },
   {  "@type":"MedicalSpecialty",
        "name":"Piles"
   },
   {  "@type":"MedicalSpecialty",
        "name":"Constipation"
   },
   {  "@type":"MedicalSpecialty",
        "name":"Pilonidal Sinus"
   },
   {  "@type":"MedicalSpecialty",
        "name":"Fistula"
   },
   {  "@type":"MedicalSpecialty",
        "name":"Varicose Veins"
   }
   ],
   
  "additionalProperty": [
    {
      "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Qualification",
      "value": "MBBS"
    },
    {
     "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Qualification",
      "value": "DNB (Surgery)"
    },
    {
      "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Qualification",
      "value": "FMAS"
    },
    {
      "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Qualification",
      "value": "Consultant Proctologist"
    }
  ]
  }
</script>


Use @Person hasCertification @Certification. then @Certification issuedBy @Organization This assumes that your "Qualification" is established by an authority that  issues the US equivalent "Board Certified"

But is the above also ok?

To be precise, your markup is not OK. Your question focus is "Qualification". But your markup is a "claim" that is not supported by a fact. A better design is to assert your Qualification as measured by a @Certification. The Certification is not your claim; it is the findings by an Authority (@Organization)

And what about medicalSpeciality?
Is it correct?

It is correct. But it would be better if you do not depend exclusively on a literal value (the name). A better approach is to link a term in a specialized vocabulary. An easy way to do this is to use sameAs and link the relevant url.  A better way is to use @DefinedTerm and a link to the authority for that term. My advice: use Wikidata when implementing @DefinedTerm

Can you give me one example in code?
